# uMatrix "forgets" my settings after every restart

Tags: macos, google-chrome, umatrix

every time I restart my Mac, I have to set every single uMatrix entry again. It doesn't remember anything. I doubt that this is the way it's supposed to be?

What can I do to make the data persist?

Comment: Are you clicking the padlock once you are satisfied with your ruleset changes?

Comment: @rhill I will try, that's probably the reason as I haven't ever done it. Write as answer and I will tick <3